# Converting FBX to three.js

Tags: python, three.js, converters, fbx

I am trying to use the FBX converter tool, located in the utils/converters/fbx/ folder, of the three.js project located here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

I have installed the FBX SDK Python 2013.3 bindings (at least I think I did that part correctly)

And I have Python 2.6 installed to C:\Python26

I copied the "FBX SDK" folder into C:\Pythons26\Lib\site-packages from C:\Program Files\Autodesk\FBX

But when I run the following command:

converty_to_threejs.py my_fbx_file.fbx test_output_file.js

I get the following error:

Could not locate the python FBX SDK!
You need to copy the FBX SDK into your python install folder such as "Python26/Lib/site-packages" folder.

I also made sure that C:\Python26 was added to my PATH system variable.

Does anyone have any idea why it wouldn't be able to find the FBX SDK folder? I put it exactly where it wants it, but it won't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you manage to solve this? If yes please post an answer to your question.

Comment: @user12411712 did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to copy *some* of the contents out of the Autodesk Python SDK into a directory that is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable (or update your PYTHONPATH to include the Autodesk SDK).

## ex. Mac OS X (Yosemite)

In the case of OS X Yosemite, neither `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages` were actually in my PYTHONPATH. So I added the following to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
# Python 2.7
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

and copied the contents of `/Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ Python\ SDK/2015.1/lib/Python27` (FbxCommon.py, fbx.so, fbxsip.so) into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

## Windows etc.

The same logic used on Mac OS X can be applied on other platforms i.e. copy `FbxCommon.py` (and any other files in the same directory - DLLs etc.) into a directory in your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 3):

don't copy the folder FBX SDK, copy the content into C:\Pythons26\Lib\site-packages
such as:
cp [FBX_SDK_ROOT]/lib/Python26_x64/* /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Mac Os X**

Download [FBX SDK](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?id=24535361&siteID=123112) and copy

> /Applications/Autodesk/FBX\ Python\ SDK/2016.1/lib/Python27

to

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7

Comment: Make sure you copy the _contents_ of /Python27 (fbx.so, FbxCommon.py, fbxsip.so) into the python folder: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, I also had the same problem:

```
Could not locate the python FBX SDK!
You need to copy the FBX SDK into your python install folder such as "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages" folder.
```

I have copied `fbx.so`, `FbxCommon.py`, and `sip.so` from `SDK_PATH/2014.1/lib/Python2.6/` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages`.

Comment: I have copied the files in the above mentioned folder but I still get the same error. any clue..

Comment: Just ran into this myself. Been literally over a year since you had the problem so hopefully you worked it out! But nonetheless please see my answer for the solution (re: PYTHONPATH).